# How to add spacing between Strings, which is coming dynamically in flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, text

I am loading a description dynamically as text, I want to design the text and insert some spacing between the text, Here is the code I am trying.

```
   Container(
              height: 240.h,
              width: Get.width / 1.1,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(
                  product.description,
                 style: subHeadingTextStyle6,
                ),
              )),
```

The output of my code is like;

[image]

I want the following spacing of the text

[image]

Comment: are you used `wordSpacing` style?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Text( product.description, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, height: 4)),
```

Update to comment: "thanks for your concern, the height property is good, but it did it equally for all line, what else I have to do to look like the picture, which I have shared in question"

**This will do the job!**

```
RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
        children: splitText(text),
              ),
            )

List<TextSpan> splitText(String text) {
  List<TextSpan> reasonList = [];
  text.split(".").forEach((element) {
    reasonList.add(TextSpan(
        text: "$element\n\n\n", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)));
  });
  return reasonList;
}
```

**So what are we doing exactly?**

First we're turning your text into a list of sentences, with `text.split(".")` which splits the text whenever it encounters a '.'

Now we are adding it in a list of TextSpan to be able to use it in RichText.
Here's the part where it makes space between every sentence `"$element\n\n\n"` I don't know if you know but \n means insert a new line. As if you hit the enter button. I used 3 \n's so that it will leave 2 lines empty after every sentence.

Comment: thanks for your concern, the height property is good, but it did it equally for all line, what else I have to do to look like the picture, which i have shared in question

Comment: Awesome, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the green tick below the upvotes. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I think just adding `\n\n` between the paragraphs should work.